# Magento: how to write own catalog navigation render function?

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

By default function Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation->renderCategoriesMenuHtml render it.
Now I would like to change the way catalog navigation render.

What I should do then?

1) write own module? - then I have to copy the same files from category module.

2) to create own logic in a template? - it is not correct. Template haven't has a logic inside itself.

3) Which ones then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a own module and rewrite the Block class as described here:
http://www.exploremagento.com/magento/override-a-magento-core-block-class.php

The `etc/config.xml` of your module would contain something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                        <navigation>YourModule_Block_Catalog_Navigation</navigation>
                    </rewrite>
                </catalog>
           </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

In your `YourModule/Block/Catalog/Navigation.php`:

```
class YourModule_Block_Catalog_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{

    public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml() {
    // your logic
    // you might call
         $parentResult = parent::renderCategoriesMenuHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: The original link in this answer was dead when I checked, but this article helped me:  http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler way to do this, without any custom module and Block class rewrites.

In the local.xml in your template layout add this:

```
<reference name="catalog.topnav">
   <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" 
          name="catalog.topnav.renderer" 
          template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Then, create the renderer.phtml file at the secified location, containing this:

```
<?php

$html = '';

$children = $menuTree->getChildren();
$parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
$childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

$counter = 1;
$childrenCount = $children->count();

$parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
$itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

foreach ($children as $child) {
    $child->setLevel($childLevel);
    $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
    $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
    $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

    $outermostClassCode = 'level'. $childLevel . ' ' . $child->getId();
    $_hasChildren = ($child->hasChildren()) ? 'has-children' : '';

    $html .= '<li '. $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) .'>';

    $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '<div class="'. $childrenWrapClass .'">';
    }

    $nextChildLevel = $childLevel + 1;

    if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
        $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
        $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'">';
        $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
        $html .=             $this->__('View All ') . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
        $html .=         '</a>';
        $html .=     '</li>';
        $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    $html .= '</li>';

    $counter++;
}

return $html;
```

Then customize the file to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much simplier way

Comment: You might not even need to add anything in the local.xml, as I was able to implement the custom template simply by placing it in the "template" folder of my custom theme at: *template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml*